# Solving complex equation, $z^4 = (z + 1)^4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

We just started learning about complex numbers, and I'm having some trouble on how to solve this problem. 
$$z^4 = (z + 1)^4$$

Was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Comment: What are youre thoughts on the problem so far Viktor?

Comment: I try to visualize the numbers in the complex plane, and then "turn-multiply" them, and see if they fit.
I guess the real part have to be 1/2.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088726/find-non-real-roots-of-an-equation

Comment: Set $w=1+\frac{1}{z}$, solve $w^4=1$ then solve with respect to $z$.

Comment: Get the zero on one side by subtraction and then use the conjugate rule twice: $x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$ using the fact that $^4$ is ${^2}^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

There is one (real) solution that you can find by inspection:

> Since $z^4 = (z+1)^4$ is kind of "symmetric" with respect to $z=-1/2$, it makes sense to evaluate this number. You will find it is a solution for the equation.

Once you find it, can you see a way of transforming this equation into a degree 3 polynomial equation? if so, and since you already know one solution, it should be easy (applying synthetic division and the quadratic formula) to find the other two roots.

Comment: Is the real solution -1/2?

Comment: Indeed! it is (I just edited my answer to add this)

Comment: Expand the right side, move it over to the left like this:$$4z^3 + 6z^2 + 4z + 1 = 0$$

Comment: Ok, very well, and can you find the other roots from there?

Comment: Yeah, polynomial division with (z + 1/2) and from there I can use the quadratic formula to find the last two/one root(s).
Thanks a lot man!

Comment: I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 7):

$(z+1)^4-z^4=((z+1)^2+z^2)((z+1)^2-z^2)=(2z^2+2z+1)(2z+1)$, which gives the answer:
$$\left\{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i,-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i,-\frac{1}{2}\right\}$$

Comment: This should probably be the most easily accessible approach for someone just introduced to complex numbers.. +1

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $z^4=(z+1)^4$ i.e $z=e^{2i\pi\over 4}(z+1), i=0,1,2,3$.

Answer (score 2):

the equation implies
$$
|z|^2=|z+1|^2
$$
so
$$
z\bar z = z\bar z+z+\bar z +1
$$
giving $$\mathfrak{R}(z) = -\frac12$$

set $z=-\frac12 + iy$ ($y \in \mathbb{R}$)

so
$$
(-\frac12 + iy)^4 = (\frac12 + iy)^4
$$
giving (since the real terms on either side cancel)
$$
4(-\frac12)^3iy + 4(-\frac12)(iy)^3 = 4(\frac12)^3iy + 4(\frac12)(iy)^3 
$$
i.e.
$$
 y-4y^3=0
$$
so the three roots of the original cubic are
$$
z= -\frac12, -\frac12 \pm \frac{i}2
$$

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $z=0$ is not solution. Thus you can divide by $z^{4}$.

You get $((z+1)/z)^4 =1$.

You know the solutions to $X^4 = 1$ in the complex numbers are $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$.

So you are down to solving  $(z+1)/z = 1$, $(z+1)/z=-1$, $(z+1)/z = i$, $(z+1)/z=-i$, which is easy.

This is basically what Jack said in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The equation implies  $z=t(z+1)$ with $|t|=1$ that means $z=\frac{t}{1-t}$ with $t\not=1$. Coming back to the equation we get $t^4=1$ that means $t\in\{-1,i,-i\}$ hence $z\in\{\frac{-1}{2},\frac{i}{1-i}, \frac{-i}{1+i}\}$