# How to solve $z^3=(iz+1)^3$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I tried to solve $z^3=(iz+1)^3$. I noticed that $(iz+1)^3=i(z-1)^3$ so $(\frac{z-1}{z})^3=i$. How to finish it?

Comment: Not quite. $(iz+1)^3 = (iz - i^2)^3 = i^3(z-i)^3 = -i(z-i)^3$

Comment: Write it as $\left(\frac{iz+1}{z}\right)^3 = 1$ then solve $w^3 = 1$ for $w$ and then $w = \frac{iz+1}{z}$ for $z$. Solutions to equations on the form $w^n  = 1$ are [the $n$th roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088726/find-non-real-roots-of-an-equation

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Factor as

$$z^3-(iz+1)^3=(z-(iz+1))(z^2+z(iz+1)+(iz+1)^2)$$ and you have a linear and a quadratic equation.

Alternatively, considering the three cubic roots of unity, solve

$$z=\sqrt[3]1(iz+1).$$

Answer (score 2):

If $z^3=(iz+1)^3$, then $|z|=|iz+1|$, hence, if $z=x+iy$, we have $y=1/2$.

Therefore $z=x+\frac{i}{2}$.

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)+\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)i=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$. Then $\omega^3=1$ and$$z^3=(iz+1)^3\iff z=iz+1\vee\omega z=iz+1\vee\omega^2z=iz+1.$$